# Combining S3 methods

Tags: r

I have created several S3 methods that I am controlling by setting classes on an object. Something like this:

```
myfun <- function (x) {
    UseMethod("myfun")
}

myfun.a <- function(x) {
  print("Type a")
}

myfun.b <- function(x) {
  print("Type b")
}

myfun.c <- function(x) {
  print("Type c")
}

myfun(structure( c(1:3), class = "a"))
# [1] "Type a"
myfun(structure( c(1:3), class = "b"))
# [1] "Type b"
myfun(structure( c(1:3), class = "c"))
# [1] "Type c"
```

Sometimes, some subset of the classes are able to share a method something like this:

```
otherfun <- function (x) {
  UseMethod("otherfun")
}

otherfun.a <- function(x) {
  print("Type a")
}

otherfun.b <- function(x) { ## Doesn't work because its only called for "b"
  print("Type b or c")
}

otherfun(structure( c(1:3), class = "a"))
# [1] "Type a"
otherfun(structure( c(1:3), class = "b"))
# [1] "Type b or c"
otherfun(structure( c(1:3), class = "c"))
# [1] "Type b or c"
```

What is the best/most correct way to implement multiple class types sharing a method? I don't want to stack classes on the object because class "b" and "c" are different in most aspects.

I'm thinking about using the default method and manually parsing the class type, something like:

```
otherfun <- function (x) {
UseMethod("otherfun")
}

otherfun.a <- function(x) {
  print("Type a")
}

otherfun.b <- function(x) {
  print("Type b or c")
}

otherfun.default <- function(x) {
  if(class(x) == "c") otherfun.b(x)
  else stop("Bad Class on x")
}

otherfun(structure( c(1:3), class = "a"))
# [1] "Type a"
otherfun(structure( c(1:3), class = "b"))
# [1] "Type b or c"
otherfun(structure( c(1:3), class = "c"))
# [1] "Type b or c"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just assign them together like this:

```
otherfun.b <- otherfun.c <- function(x) print("Type b or c")
```

Comment: I like that, thanks... I'll accept it as an answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 4):

Define an appropriate class hierarcy

```
a <- structure(list(), class=c("a", "base"))
b <- structure(list(), class=c("b", "b_or_c", "base"))
c <- structure(list(), class=c("c", "b_or_c", "base"))
```

and implement methods at appropriate places

```
im <- function(x) UseMethod("im")
im.a <- function(x) "I'm a"
im.b_or_c <- function(x) paste("I'm b_or_c:", class(x)[1])
```

In action:

```
> im(a)
[1] "I'm a"
> im(b)
[1] "I'm b_or_c: b"
> im(c)
[1] "I'm b_or_c: c"
```

Usually classes share methods because of shared structure. Defining the appropriate hierarchy allows re-use of both the method and the data structure.

Objects of the same class should always have the same class hierarchy, so a 'b' will always be a 'b_or_c'. This is enforced in many object systems; S3 is allowing you to play very fast and loose with class definitions. One way to enforce a common hierarchy is to use 'constructors' that centralize the creation of the class

```
base = function(base_data="base only", ..., class)
    ## construct an instance that contains base data, other data (...),
    ## and an appropriate class specification
    structure(list(base_data=base_data, ...), class=c(class, "base"))

b_or_c = function(b_or_c_data="b or c", ..., class)
    ## construct a b_or_c instance with relevant data, using the
    ## base constructor
    base(b_or_c_data=b_or_c_data, ..., class=c(class, "b_or_c"))

b = function(b_data="b only", ...)
    ## like b_or_c, but for a 'b' instance
    b_or_c(b_data=b_data, ..., class="b")
```

which in action looks like

```
> b(b_data="ima b")
$base_data
[1] "base only"

$b_or_c_data
[1] "b or c"

$b_data
[1] "ima b"

attr(,"class")
[1] "b"      "b_or_c" "base"
```

Even if there are no methods on b_or_c, it might still be useful to have the class to represent data that is shared between the b and c classes. If not, well, remove the b_or_c constructor and adjust `b()` to call `base()`.

It might be that `a` shares a method with `b` and `c`, in which case the method should be implemented on the base class. When `a` shares a method with `b` but not `c`, then it is typical to write a helper function that the a and b methods call after initial processing; often this kind of pattern (where a method is implemented on objects from only some classes in different parts of the hierarchy) suggests that the class hierarchy is not designed appropriately

```
.foo_helper = function(x) {
    ## implement shared functionality here 
}

foo.a = function(x) {
    ## do a-specfic things here, then
    data = some_manipulation_of_a
    .foo_helper(data)
}

foo.b = function(x) {
    data = some_manipulation_of_b
    .foo_helper(data)
}
```

Likely this would be a more realistic pattern than the accepted answer -- `a` and `c` likely require separate processing (since they have different data structures) before calling some shared functionality.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me to keep the base class in the class list. I'm going to accept @g-grothendieck 's answer, though. 

Your style looks much harder to maintain and use. For example, do I mark all "b" and "c" objects with "b_or_c", or only the ones I expect to need mixed methods?

What if all the mixed methods get removed in favor of unique methods? 

What if I realize "a" can share a method with "c" at some point?

Comment: I elaborated a bit in my response.